# Как устроен рендер ui в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Меня интересует как именно устроин рендер с помощью gpu? На основе ui, с помощью ратерезатора, генерируются текстуры, которые затем отправляются на gpu? Или же на основе ui генерируются шейдеры, которые вычисляют отображение(именно вычисляют\строят, а не передают текстуры сгенерированные на cpu)?

Comment: Изучайте исходники QtQuick модуля, вряд ли кто-то развёрнуто Вам тут ответит.

Comment: Вопрос довольно специфичный. Не пробовали самостоятельно в исходниках Qt поискать? :) Они доступны, например по QWidget: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp

Comment: Я понимаю что вопрос не простой, но все же расчитываю что здесь найдется хотя бы один настоящий профессионал в своем деле, который походу своей деятельности уже изучал исходники самостоятельно или же получил информацию каким-то другим путемя и не прочь поделится.

Comment: @ixSci а мне не нужно развернуто. Я уже перечислил возможные варианты, осталось только сказать какой именно и если что есть подкорректировать, то буквально предложения на это хватит.

Comment: @gil9red нужно копать куда глбже, т.к. сами виджеты и компоненты которые они вызывают в приватном исполненинии актуально кода не содержат.  Отрисовка вынесена в отдельную подсиситему и состоит из абстрактных слоев вокруг реализации и вызовов для каждой платформы, различных драйверов и оболочек. Именно из-за таких сложностей Qt использует PIMPL, чтобы програму можно было использовать при разных конфигурациях платформы без перекомпиляции самой программы, только имея библиотеку нужной версси , собранную под эту платформу.

Comment: @Swift, это был пример. Но за пояснение про PIMPL спасибо, это будет многим полезно :)

Comment: @gil9red что значит "был пример"? Вы человеку, о котором ничего не знаете, дали... так ради примера.. первый пришедший в голову лист кода на миллион строк? Спасибо!

Comment: @DmitriyM, не понимаю ваше возмущение: 1) я не знал для какого виджета вам нужны подробности и написал что нужно в исходниках искать и привел пример 2) я ту ссылку нашел в гугле по запросу `QWidget.cpp git`, а значит и вы могли это сделать, либо на самом том сайте найти нужный вам виджет, либо через поисковик поиском по сайту `site:code.qt.io QLabel.cpp` 3) это был комментарий к вашему вопросу, а не ответ, поэтому не обязан был решить ваш вопрос (подсказка и направление ведьесть) 4) год назад я копался в исходниках QErrorMessage, чтобы разобраться в своей проблеме (мотивация была) и вы сможете

Comment: Небольшой спойлер: GPU-рендеринга в обычных виджетах нет, поэтому можете даже не пытаться там искать. Я указал где искать.

Comment: И ещё, код Qt лучше всего изучать с этим [сайтом](https://code.woboq.org), т.к. там есть отличная навигация.

Comment: @gil9red согласен с Вами, это не ответ, это разнос сознания! Представьте что вы испытываете какую-либо слоность и идете в сообщество за советом(помощью). И тут Вам в коменте говорят - а вы здесь не смотрели? И дают ссылку на миллион строк кода. Ваша реакция?

Comment: @DmitriyM, буду благодарен хоть за какую-нибудь подсказку в направлении решении моей проблемы. У Qt в исходниках много кода и привыкайте к тому, что в больших проектах придется видеть миллионы строк. А еще, QWidget это основной виджет для всего визуального в Qt: кнопки, окна, поля ввода, таблицы, списки и т.п. поэтому в нем есть смысл искать. Воспользовался сайтом, предложенным ixSci и нашел кое-что интересное для вашего исследования: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qopenglwindow.cpp.html Кст, попрошу больше не флудить

Answer (score 0):

Ответ сильно зависит от платформы и версии библиотеки и режима\наличия компонентов при построении. Для отрисовки используются внешние библиотеки и сама подсистема состоит и зависит от многих компонент.

Ответ одним предложением: все вышеперечисленное и  плюс еще" т.к. Qt может рабоать на системах без оконного интерфейса, отрисовывая с помощью драйвера экранного буфера или его аналога. Если последний от NVIDIA - то подход близок к последнему варианту, но вся работа с GPU делается в драйвере.

Comment: А можете пояснить почему только на nvidia? Какое отношение марка видеокарты имеет к логике реализованной в ui-библиотеки? И при чем оконный интерфейс когда это всего-лишь библиотека надстройка над gapi?

Comment: @DmitriyM Потому как внутри fb драйвер может быть реализован по разному. Их драйвер - закрытый код даже.. никто не знает. `то всего-лишь библиотека надстройка над gapi` - это неверно. Это библиотека  переносимого GUI (а так же много чего еще, - сетевых сокетов, баз данных, и пр.) Потому что не все системы одинаков.не все платформы имеют gapi.  не все платформы имеют оконный API. На Windows и в X-WIndows серевере Qt использует gapi внутри нативных окон. Но может быть откомпилирована для использования нативных элементов управления. Последнее невозможно на Маке и анроидах.

Comment: @DmitriyM причем Qt может использовать и высокоуровневый GAPI (там никаких текстур и шейдеров не видно) и нискоуровневый - OpenGL. Опять таки задается ключами компиляции библиотеки.